# Is it possible to make Javascript interact with the GPIO pins?

Tags: gpio, javascript

I want to make a game with Javascript with LED and pushbutton interaction. My problem is: I don't know how to make Javascript "talk" with the GPIO pins. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/pi-gpio ?

Comment: No ill have a look thx.

Comment: If that works for you please add it as an answer yourself.  I'm not sure if node.js modules can be used outside of node but I believe they can -- if you need help with that look/ask on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).  Or maybe you'll want to use node as the server, it is a pretty cool thing.

Comment: @goldilocks If by "using outside node" you means in a web browser, surely not. The [pi-gpio](https://github.com/rakeshpai/pi-gpio) use the gpio sysfs to access to gpio, then it need a node server. I don't think there is a web browser API that give access to raspberry gpio.

Comment: @mpromonet You are most likely right.  I did notice there is a node system for "browserifying" modules for use on the client, but there are probably restrictions on that WRT hardware access.  If the OP is programming games in js I'd think a node server would be right up his alley anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. you can use Node-Red with gpio contrib. Its visual programming with javascript.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-gpio

Also, you can try cylonjs. It supports many platforms other than raspberry pi.

http://cylonjs.com/documentation/platforms/raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 0):

Yes (as noted by @mpromonet);

```
var gpio = require("pi-gpio");

gpio.open(16, "output", function(err) {     // Open pin 16 for output 
    gpio.write(16, 1, function() {          // Set pin 16 high (1) 
        gpio.close(16);                     // Close pin 16 
    });
});
```

Documentation [pi-gpio node.js based library npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pi-gpio).

Answer (score 0):

[WebIOPi](https://code.google.com/p/webiopi/) has a REST API that can be accessed via a [JavaScript client](https://code.google.com/p/webiopi/wiki/JAVASCRIPT), so I believe that should fit your needs.